# Is there a way I use cluster created in one github workflow in another?

Tags: github, workflow, sharing, container-registry, k3d

I have 2 github workflows - build and test. The build workflow builds code and push image to a registry (docker/build-push-action@v4) . The test workflow covers testing, and must use the images built from build workflow. Ideally we would push image to a registry that the other workflow can access. But,I have some constraints with using ghcr/ other registries. Therefore I am exploring using local registry we can create with k3d. So in build workflow I make a k3d cluster + registry, build and push images to this registry. The test workflow however, cannot access this cluster/ images. Any pointers on making this work?

Explored upload-artifacts to share between workflows. Does not seem to be solution for building and uploading container images.